# how to implement machine learning model (SVC) using training,validation and testing set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I've divided the data into three sets.
[image]

After this, I'm trying to implement this in SVM like this:
[image]

I am not sure if it is the correct way of doing it or not, as the difference between the scores I am getting and the ones mentioned in the papers is huge.

The end goal I want to achieve is to get accuracy, precision, and recall for all three sets.

Comment: Please do **not** post screenshots - see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting huge score that you aren't expecting, it maybe due to an unknown data leak. It all depends on how your data is. *e.g.,* by default `train_test_split` has shuffle as `True`. if the data is time sensitive, that means the model has already peaked into future - and therefore this high accuracy.

Try with:

```
train_test_split(..., shuffle=False)
```